# What are the ways to modify the font in android and how to set exact size for the boldness in android?

Tags: android

I want to know What are the ways to modify the font in android and how to set exact size for the boldness in android text.

Comment: Yes.I want to set size for boldness. I want to control the boldness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that can be achieved by few ways,

First you can set custom TypeFace to your Text with [setTypeFace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29)

Also you can set size of the text using [setTextSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29)

And if you want any HTML font style for your Text you can do it using [fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)